# Error: You do not have read/write permission to the serial port

Tags: android, serial-port

I have sample application to read from serial port from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/source/checkout).

I have set device to `ttyUSB1(usbserial)` and Baud rate to `9600` .

but when I click on console I am getting `Error: You do not have read/write permission to the serial port`

my logcat is

```
  08-22 15:01:25.210: W/System.err(14524): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command:   
  [/system/bin/su] Working Directory: null Environment: null
  08-22 15:01:25.210: W/System.err(14524):  at   
  java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)

   08-22 15:01:25.211: W/System.err(14524):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:168)
   08-22 15:01:25.211: W/System.err(14524):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:241)
   08-22 15:01:25.212: W/System.err(14524):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:184)
   08-22 15:01:25.212: W/System.err(14524):     at android_serialport_api.SerialPort.<init>  
   (SerialPort.java:47)
  08-22 15:01:25.212: W/System.err(14524):  at   
  android_serialport_api.sample.Application.getSerialPort(Application.java:46)
  08-22 15:01:25.213: W/System.err(14524):  at  
  android_serialport_api.sample.SerialPortActivity.onCreate(SerialPortActivity.java:78)
  08-22 15:01:25.213: W/System.err(14524):  at   
  android_serialport_api.sample.Sending01010101Activity.onCreate(Sending01010101Activity.java:31)
  08-22 15:01:25.214: W/System.err(14524):  at   
  android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
  08-22 15:01:25.214: W/System.err(14524):  at   
  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
  08-22 15:01:25.214: W/System.err(14524):  at   
   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
   08-22 15:01:25.214: W/System.err(14524):     at  
  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
 08-22 15:01:25.215: W/System.err(14524):   at   
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
 08-22 15:01:25.215: W/System.err(14524):   at  
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
 08-22 15:01:25.215: W/System.err(14524):   at   
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  08-22 15:01:25.216: W/System.err(14524):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
  08-22 15:01:25.216: W/System.err(14524):  at  
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
  08-22 15:01:25.216: W/System.err(14524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native   
 Method)
 08-22 15:01:25.216: W/System.err(14524):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 08-22 15:01:25.217: W/System.err(14524):   at   
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
  08-22 15:01:25.217: W/System.err(14524):  at    
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
     08-22 15:01:25.217: W/System.err(14524):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     08-22 15:01:25.217: W/System.err(14524): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or          
    directory
    08-22 15:01:25.218: W/System.err(14524):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
   08-22 15:01:25.219: W/System.err(14524):     at  
   java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
   08-22 15:01:25.219: W/System.err(14524):     ... 21 more
```

How can I resolve this.

please help to solve this.

Comment: post the code and logcat here

Comment: I have posted my logcat and code i got from link which I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: have you declared this permission  in your manifest android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Nope. as these permissions are required to read/write from Storage so I didnt

Answer (score 1):

If you are using serial port application go to file `SerialPort.java`

change the line:

```
su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/su");
```

to

```
su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/xbin/su");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: You do not have read/write permission to the serial port

**Just change `bin` to `xbin`.**

like this, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/xbin/su");`